# Sending envelopes via an integration from (and only) a particular account in an organization

Tags: docusignapi

For a DocuSign demo/production environment for an *organization* with several *accounts*, if you create an eSignature app for creating/sending envelopes how do you specify which account any envelopes are sent from when using the API username for a user with access to multiple *accounts* in the *organization*?

**Background:** in the present case, the particular *organization* has several *accounts*. An app was created in demo environment while in the admin for one of the *accounts* to get the integration key, etc. Having created the app and tested it, however, the envelopes were sent from a different (unintended) *account* in the same *organization*. On inspection, the API username for the relevant admin user is the same on each account and the app is present in *Apps & Keys* for both accounts (and DocuSign docs refer to an app being available to accounts in the same environment). In the demo environment, it is desirable that envelopes are, however, sent from the intended *account* rather than the other *account*. In production, it is essential that envelopes come from the correct production *account*. Noted that parts of the DocuSign documentation refer to apps being available across *accounts* in an environment, but I was not clear how to ensure it is still sent from the intended account where a user has access to multiple *accounts*.

- For the demo environment, is there an admin setting at the
  *organization* level to set which *account* envelopes should be sent from via an app that has been granted consent in the demo
  environment and configured with the API username of a user with access to multiple accounts? Or does this depend on using an API username which has access to one account and not others?
- In the production environment, as the go-live process will include selecting to promote the
  integration key to a specific production *account* this will presumably ensure that envelopes are **only** sent from that production *account* when using the integration provided only that *account* in the *organization* uses the specific app (even for the API username of a user with access to multiple accounts)? However, to ensure this is the case (e.g. in case the same app were used for another production *account* in the same *organization* for the same user), is the best way to do this to create a unique user on the intended *account* (rather than using a user with
  access to multiple *accounts* in the *organization*) and use their API
  username to configure the specific integration to that account in each case (i.e. don't use admins for example with access to multiple *accounts*)? Or is there a better way to do this (e.g. admin setting in the interface or via API)?

Comment: are you using JWT? did you use Admin consent for the entire org?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, JWT. The consent process followed the process to obtain individual consent (from here: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JWT individual consent, you are selecting the account by selecting two GUID values.

1. The userID value (GUID) to obtain a token using JWT (the user to be impersonated).
2. The accountID value (GUID) for the account you use when making API calls, it's indicated in the baseURL for API calls.

You can change 1 and 2 if you obtain consent, but they have to be from the same account for this to work.